# How do you filter records by the time of day in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a bunch of records that have a `DateTime` stored on them that is only used to pull out the time of day (i.e. 6:00 p.m.) and I'd like to filter them by the time of day. For example, I'd like to get all the records where the time of day is between 10:00 a.m. and 2:00 p.m., regardless of what day that timestamp is for.

Is there a way to do this in Rails? I realize that `DateTime` might not be the easiest/best way to store this data, so I'm open to changing that. Also, I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 3):

With Postgres you can use typecasting to convert your datetime/timestamp fields to a time, for example:

```
select * from posts where created_at::time BETWEEN '10:00:00' and '14:00:00';
```

So, in Rails, you should be able to do:

```
Post.where('start_at::time BETWEEN ? AND ?', '10:00:00', '14:00:00')
```

And Postgres is smart enough to understand AM/PM format also:

```
Post.where('start_at::time BETWEEN ? AND ?', '10:00:00 AM', '02:00:00 PM')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the standard timestamps that are generated as part of the Rails model generator, then you're using `DateTime` for those timestamps.

Assuming that this is the `created_at` model attribute (it doesn't have to be, change it the value that you're using), here's how to do it:

In raw SQL, the query you're looking for is `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE created_at BETWEEN FIRST_DATE AND SECOND_DATE;` which can be represented in Rails as:

```
@first_date  = DateTime.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, 10, 0, 0, 0)
@second_date = DateTime.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, 14, 0, 0, 0)

Model.where(created_at: @first_date..@second_date)
```

The `..` (which is a sequence operator) tells Rails to build the BETWEEN query using `@first_date` and `@second_date` as the `FIRST_DATE` and `SECOND_DATE` values in the raw SQL query.

Comment: You missed the "regardless of what day that timestamp is for" part of the question.